# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^H (U+0008)

Tags: latex, tex

I installed MacTex from brew `brew install mactex-no-gui --cask`

`test.tex`

```
\documentclass{jarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
mytest--m=testmode テストを行う

\end{document}
```

I try to compile this this simple text with `platex`

It shows this error.

I guess it is related to unicode setting ??
because I put some Japanese character in it.

How can I fix it?

```
$platex test.tex

This is e-pTeX, Version 3.14159265-p3.8.3-191112-2.6 (utf8.euc) (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=platex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
pLaTeX2e <2020-02-02>+3 (based on LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5)
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/platex/base/jarticle.cls
Document Class: jarticle 2020/01/03 v1.8e Standard pLaTeX class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/platex/base/jsize10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./test.aux)

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^H (U+0008)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 mytest^^H
             --m=crond テストを行う
```

Comment: Your example works without error. Both your platex format and several package are not up to date. Can you try to update to the current version? With vanilla texlive, I would run `tlmgr update -all`, no idea if this will also work for texlive installed via brew

Comment: I push delete `mytest--m`  between `mytest` and `--m` there is something invisible, I need to push delete twice to delete `t`, and it works.